# Installing the Waypoints plugin

Tags: 8, javascript

I’m using Drupal 8.5.4 and I have installed the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module. I’m trying to install the [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) plugin without success via the module: [jQuery waypoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/waypoints) (still on alpha1 for D8). Is there a way to simply install the plugin manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yupp, simply download the [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) library, extract and rename the folder to just `waypoints`, then put it into `themes/custom/MYTHEME/libs` or into `modules/custom/MYMODULE/libs` and follow one of the following instructions:

[Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)

[Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module)

---

Basically all you have to do is to create the corresponding `MYTHEME/MYMODULE.libraries.yml` file

```
waypoints:
  js:
    libs/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

and then attach the library to all pages via [`hook_page_attachments()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.2.x) or [`hook_page_attachments_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.2.x) inside the `MYTHEME.theme` or `MYMODULE.module` file.

```
<?php

function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter(&$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'MYTHEME-or-MYMODULE/waypoints';
}
```